# how to redirect to a custom post template

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I'm building a website in which there is a page where I collect a list of works/projects; I created a file called `work.php` where I made the template of this page, but when I try to view a single custom post (when I press on a single item), it says that the page doesn't exist.

Then, my question is: do I have to create a custom template like `work-post.php` for the custom post or do I have to use `single.php`?

P.S. I'm using a custom post called `work` type I made.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are doing. Do you have a CPT called "work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you CPT is called "**work**", i.e. you have registered it using

```
register_post_type('work', $args);
```

you have to create a file called **`'single-work.php'`** and that will be used to show the singular work post.

If you don't create that file the file `'single.php'`,if present, will be used by WordPress. If even the `'single.php'` does not exist in your theme, then the `'index.php'` file will be used.

Please see [**WordPress Template Hierarchy**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) on Codex for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom single page file. Or search about template post in wordpress.